# Having a moment (interjecting?)

Tags: word-usage, american-english, spoken-english

https://www.urbandictionary.com/author.php?author=Labr4t

Here is the use of "**have a moment**" natural?( apart from its other  meanings)?

> **The phrase 'Having a moment' should be used whenever a conversation between yourself and someone else is interrupted, either verbally or through the unwanted presence of someone.**
>
> > *Does not necessarily mean the you are actually having a moment.
> >     Boy and Girl are having a discussion about motorized seesaws at a party, Random Guy appears near them, attempting to interject the conversation.*
> >
> > > Girl: "Uh sorry, we're having a moment right now" 
> > >       Boy: *nods* 
> > >       Random Guy: "Oh, uh, sorry" Exeunt

Source: The Urban Dictionary.

---

### **And is this use common in AmE:**

> to not be acting normally for a short time, for example because you are not thinking about what you are doing, or because you are feeling a

**Source: The Cambridge Dictionary.**

***The Dictionary says it's a British phrase, so is it used in AmE as well?***

Answer (score 2):

In contemporary, informal American English, if two people are *having a moment*, they are sharing an intimate experience.

Here's an example from the American sitcom *Just Shoot Me*

> Dennis Finch : You shot the cover of Rolling Stone? Wow, man. I'm impressed.
>
> Elliot DiMauro : Thanks. Coming from you, that means a lot.
>
> Dennis Finch : Wait a minute. Are you being sarcastic?
>
> Elliot DiMauro : No. Are you?
>
> Dennis Finch : No. You?
>
> Elliot DiMauro : I'll tell you what. We'll both answer together on the count of three. Ready? One, two, three.
>
> Elliot DiMauro , Dennis Finch : Nnnnnoooooyyyeeeeesssss... No!
>
> Elliot DiMauro : I think we just had a moment.
>
> Dennis Finch : No, we didn't because I was messing with you. Hey, everyone! Elliot thought we had a moment!
>
> https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0617867/characters/nm0170186

If two people are having a deep, personal conversation, they might be *having a moment*.  The Urban Dictionary "definition" is a joke (like a lot of what's in Urban Dictionary, which is why you should not take anything posted on that site as authoritative). The joke is, having a conversation about seesaws is not *having a moment* - it's not an intimate conversation - and so making this untrue statement may be humorous.

Comment: And what about the other meaning? Is it common in AE?( one about feeling down)

Comment: So is the second meaning (under the heading of "The Cambridge Dictionary " common?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish, I've never heard the phrase used that way.

Comment: @its-about-english - yes, what you copy-pasted looks like it got cut off, but this is another common meaning. E.g. A & B are talking and all of a sudden A starts crying. B: Are you ok? A: Yeah, I’m just having a moment.